# Trouble passing JS function as parameter

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox, parameter-passing, quotes

JS Newbie here: I am trying to use JS to append some HTML to a form fieldset when a checkbox is clicked:
First, I added the event onchange to the checkbox, and set it to my function:

```
<fieldset class="lapsFS" id="manLapsFS"><legend>Manual laps</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="lapsCB" value="manlapsCB" 
           onchange="cbHandleChange(this, addLap, 'manLapsFS', clearFS, 'manLapsFS');">
    <label>Enable manual laps</label><br>
</fieldset>
```

cbHandleChange parameters:
1. checkbox to handle
2. function to call when checkbox is on
3. parameter for 2
4. function to call when checkbox is off
5. parameter for 4

here is cbHandleChange:

```
function cbHandleChange(cb, funcOn, paramOn, funcOff, paramOff) {
    if(cb.checked == true) { 
        funcOn.call(paramOn); 
    } else {
        funcOff.call(paramOff); 
    } 
}
```

and this is the function passed as parameter 4:

```
function clearFS(fs) {
    fs.innerHTML = "";
}
```

I tried both to put single quotes in `onchange="cbHandleChange(this, addLap, 'manLapsFS', clearFS, 'manLapsFS');"` rather than to not put them, but still I get a

> cbHandleChange is not defined

where am I wrong?

EDIT: I edited cbHandleChange in my question because I forgot a curly brace.

Comment: probably defined cbHandleChange in the wrong place. What is addLap ?

Comment: On your output (final page code) check if the function is defined before it is being called

Comment: oh right, check the 1 Answer it's the curly braces

Comment: Don't use `call`. Just `if (cb.checked) funcOn(paramOn); else funcOff(paramOff);`

Comment: I edited the question because the curly braces was not missing: I deleted it for mistake. Finally I managed to got it to work: here's the working cbHandleChange:  `function cbHandleChange(cb, funcOn, paramOn, funcOff, paramOff) {  
 if(cb.checked == true) {  
  funcOn(paramOn);  
 } else {  
  funcOff(paramOff);  
 }  
}`

Comment: Change `fs.innerHTML = ""` to `document.getElementById(fs).innerHTML = ""`

Answer (score 0):

you have issue with curly braces

```
function cbHandleChange(cb, funcOn, paramOn, funcOff, paramOff) {
    if(cb.checked == true) {
        funcOn.call(paramOn);
    }       
    else 
        funcOff.call(paramOff);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, that was an error pasting the code: I deleted the brace after "else" while deleting a comment. Function is actually this: 
`function cbHandleChange(cb, funcOn, paramOn, funcOff, paramOff) {
    if(cb.checked == true) {
        funcOn.call(paramOn);
    }       
    else {
        funcOff.call(paramOff);
    }
}`